# Voodoo era memories

Tags: riddle, knowledge

At first, I was a fictional alien detection base.

Three years later, I was founded as a memory manufacturing corporation.

What am I?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth:_Final_Conflict)?

Comment: I was thinking [this based on the title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_3dfx_graphics_processing_units) + [this based on the alien base](https://xcom.fandom.com/wiki/Avenger_(XCOM_2))  but I couldn't match the memory corporation from the list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_hardware_manufacturers#Random-access_memory_(RAM)_modules)

Comment: @flinty ROT13 Lbhe svefg yvfg vf pbeerpg, ohg xrrc va zvaq gung gur gvgyr whfg tvirf n puebabybtvpny uvag. Frpbaq yvfg vf abg gur nafjre. Lbhe guveq yvfg vaqrrq pbagnvaf gur nafjre, ohg lbh arrq fgebat xabjyrqtr gb vqragvsl vg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm going to say this **ADATA**. 
>  The title contains *voodoo* so I thought of the [3dfx graphics cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_3dfx_graphics_processing_units) made during the 90s.

> There is a list of companies that make computer memory [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_hardware_manufacturers#Random-access_memory_(RAM)_modules) . I suspected **ADATA** because it contained A.D and that could be an acronym used elsewhere (like a sci-fi film or game) to mean *alien detection*.

> Apparently, one of the games that was released free with 3dfx voodoo cards was *Incoming (1998)* by *Rage Software*. I've never played it, but after much searching I found [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKE6YLI4K3Y) showing the first mission in the game and its intro mentions defending **A.D.A.T.A** - the *Anomaly Detection And Tracking Array* during a UFO attack.

> Three years later is 2001, and that's when **ADATA**, the Taiwanese memory and storage company was founded.

---

> I also spent quite a lot of time thinking it was **SanDisk** as they're a memory company and notably they changed their name from **Sun**-Disk in 1995 following a complaint by Sun Microsystems ... about the middle of the '*voodoo* era'. And I thought this might be relevant because there are a number of UFO and conspiracy sites which mention an artifact called the Sun Disk used to communicate with ancient aliens.

Comment: You got it! Being older than I'd like to declare, I had actually played the game and quite liked it. One of these days I was looking to buy a HDD, and I was astonished to see it being an actual company, so I made this riddle immediately. Liked your twist, too.